# How to implement 'whats visible on the right = visible on the left'?

Tags: angularjs

How to implement next thing?:
  e.g. from left side I have list of items and it's sub items, and it's sub Items...no end
When I click show/hide icon, the subItems shows/hides.(like expand/collapse). here an img:

[image]

from right side I list the same items and subItems with all subLevels. But I need to have next functionality:
 when I open 1 level from left side, also one level shown from right side.
when open 3 levels from left side, 3 levels are shown from right side.
how to implement it?
maybe to pass variables for all levels?? or one variable where to set levels?

items and subItems list from left side implemented:

```
         <div class="hoverFolder drag btn ">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="end end"  flex="10" ng-click="vm.setCurrent(iter.id);vm.shouldShowChildren[$index]=!vm.shouldShowChildren[$index]; vm.viewSubItemOnRight(vm.shouldShowChildren[$index]);">
                <div>
                    <md-icon style="font-size:20px;" md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right"  ng-class="{ open: vm.shouldShowChildren[$index] }"></md-icon>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="vm.shouldShowChildren[$index]"  class="collapseChildren" dragula="'folder-bag'">
            <div ng-repeat="child in items.children track by $index"  ng-include="'app/components/work/leftsidenav-work/work-item-child.tmpl.html' "></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: How did you implement the dropdown menu? Are you using Bootstrap or other plugins?

Comment: updated info. No bootstrap.